# How to compare multidimensional array element with array of hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, multidimensional-array, hash

I am trying to implement dynamic filter on data. I have multidimensional array of filter option:

```
filter_option = [["accountid", "<", "2"],["first_name", "=", "John"],["lastname", "=", "deo"]]
```

and array of hashes as:

```
reports = [{accountid: 1, first_name: "Elen", lastname: "Adam"},{accountid: 1, first_name: "niokie", lastname: "c"},{accountid: 2, first_name: "john", lastname: "deo"},{accountid: 4, first_name: "sherry", lastname: "b"},{accountid: 3, first_name: "Jimmy", lastname: "S"}]
```

All filter option elements should match each hash of `report` array. For example, in `filter_option`, we have `account_id < 2`, `first_name = john` and `last_name = deo`. So I need that hash, which satisfies all these filters.

If `filter_option` is:

```
filter_option = [["accountid", ">", "2"]]
```

then the output should be:

```
filtered_report = [{accountid: 4, first_name: "sherry", lastname: "b"},{accountid: 3, first_name: "Jimmy", lastname: "S"}]
```

If filter option is:

```
filter_option = [["accountid", "=", "2"],["first_name","=","john"],["lastname","=","deo"]]
```

then the output should be:

```
filtered_report = [{accountid: 2, first_name: "john", lastname: "deo"}]
```

If filter option is:

```
filter_option = [["accountid", ">", "3"],["first_name","=","sherry"],["lastname","=","b"]]
```

then the output should be:

```
filtered_report = [{accountid: 4, first_name: "sherry", lastname: "b"}]
```

I am not getting a solution that I need. Does anyone know what the best solution is to get the output that I need?

I wrote code as below:

```
filtered_report = []
  filter_option.each do |f|
    reports.each do |r|
      r.each do |k,v|
        if f[1] == "="
          if f[0].to_sym == k && v == f[2]  
            filtered_report << r
          end
        elsif f[1] == ">"
          if f[0].to_sym == k && v > f[2].to_i
            filtered_report << r
          end
        elsif f[1] == "<"
          if f[0].to_sym == k && v < f[2].to_i
            filtered_report << r
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

When I execute this code, I will get output like:

```
filtered_report = [{:accountid=>1, :first_name=>"Elen", :lastname=>"Adam"}, {:accountid=>1, :first_name=>"Elen", :lastname=>"Adam"}, {:accountid=>2, :first_name=>"john", :lastname=>"deo"}, {:accountid=>2, :first_name=>"john", :lastname=>"deo"}]
```

which is not correct because there is no one hash in array that satisfies all filters given in `filter_option` array, and output should be `nil`.

Comment: Not clear what you have. Do not introduce variables/methods without explanation. How is filter option different from `filter_option`? How is `report` array different from `reports` array?

Comment: Not clear why output should be `nil` rather than an empty array in your last explanation.

Comment: @sawa i will keep in mind next time during ask the question and thanks for your suggestion.  And yes, output should be come as empty array not nil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the code below

```
    filtered_report = []

    filter_option_length = filter_option.length
    reports.each do |report|    
        condition_satisfied_flag = 0
        filter_option.each do |filter|
            if filter[1] == "="
                condition_satisfied_flag += 1 if report[filter[0].to_sym].to_s.downcase == filter[2].downcase               
            end

            if filter[1] == "<"
                condition_satisfied_flag += 1 if report[filter[0].to_sym].to_s.downcase < filter[2].downcase
            end

            if filter[1] == ">"
                condition_satisfied_flag += 1 if report[filter[0].to_sym].to_s.downcase > filter[2].downcase
            end 
        end
        filtered_report << report if condition_satisfied_flag == filter_option_length
    end
```

Comment: your answer is completely true as i need. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Your code implements an `or` relationship between the filter options - if either of them is correct for an item, that item will be added to the result (sometimes more than once...)

To implement as `and`, you need to make sure all rules pass for an item before adding it to the result. The easiest way to implement it is to assume the result contains *all* elements, then remove any element which *does not* pass a rule:

```
  filtered_report = reports.dup
  filter_option.each do |f|
    filtered_report.reject! do |r|
      !r.any? do |k,v|
        if f[1] == "="
          if f[0].to_sym == k && v == f[2]  
           true
          end
        elsif f[1] == ">"
          if f[0].to_sym == k && v > f[2].to_i
            true
          end
        elsif f[1] == "<"
          if f[0].to_sym == k && v < f[2].to_i
            true
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

`reject!` removes all elements for which the block returns true, and `any?` returns true if any of blocks returned true.

This is not very rubyish, though... with a bit of changes to the `filtered_option` array, you can make this much more succinctly:

```
filter_option = [[:accountid, "<", 2],[:first_name, "==", "John"],[:lastname, "==", "deo"]] 
reports.select do |h|
  filter_option.any? do |field, op, value|
    h[field].send(op, value)
  end
end
=> [{:accountid=>1, :first_name=>"Elen", :lastname=>"Adam"}, 
    {:accountid=>1, :first_name=>"niokie", :lastname=>"c"}, 
    {:accountid=>2, :first_name=>"john", :lastname=>"deo"}]

reports.select do |h|
  filter_option.all? do |field, op, value|
    h[field].send(op, value)
  end
end
=> []
```

What does the above code do?

`select` returns only elements for which the block returns `true`.

`any?` returns `true` if any runs of the block (once for each element) returns `true`.

`all?` returns 'true' if *all* runs of the block return `true`.

`send(op, value)` actually *runs* the operator on the element (i.e. `"niokie" == "John"`), and returns its value.

Comment: your approach is right of use && instead of || in match condition and i will follow your way also to get the solution. Thanks.